# Как исправить конфигурацию при сбитом языке ввода логина и пароля?

Tags: ubuntu, загрузка, клавиатура, локаль

Добрый вечер!

История такая — правил файл `/usr/share/X11/xkb`, поменял местами «ru» с «en», ребут, теперь при загрузке английский язык отсутствует, а логин и пароль на английском. Как при загрузке прервать загрузку графической оболочки для того, чтобы подправить конфиг?

Answer (score 3):

В загрузке grub есть есть загрузко консольного режима. Или когда всё загрузится можно сочетаниями клавишь ctrl+alt+F1-12 или разные вариации с клавишами F переключать консоли они будут в текстовом режиме.

Comment: Всё правильно, только скомканно. Заходи в консоль `Ctrl + Alt + F1` и правь обратно. Раскладка для консоли задаётся отдельно от X11

Comment: да, помогло, но не совсем.
ctrl+alt+f1 выдает такую вот красивую картинку:
http://imageshost.ru/photo/52937/id1174184.html

Comment: У меня такая же картинка на виртуальной машине вылазит, когда я вырубаю систему.

Answer (score 3):

Варианты.

1. Загрузиться в режиме восстановления (во время загрузки grub - нажать Shift, выбрать recovery mode, затем выбрать "Drop to root shell prompt"). У вас будут права рута, и вы сможете менять конфиги.
2. Загрузиться с Live CD или подобного. Подмонтировать диск с Linux и исправить конфиг.

Answer (score 0):

Есть небольшая, но вероятность, что в системе включено сочетание клавиш для остановки x-server.По умолчанию до версии 9,04 было Ctrl+Alt+Backspace